# Gmail API: python application error

Tags: javascript, python, gmail, gmail-api

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name

i executed python quickstart.py
and it opened browser-like window.
i've typed my email address and the password and reached a screen where i need to press "allow" button

when I did that I get this error:
"You've reached this page because we have dtected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The age you attempted to load cannot display properly if script is disabled. Please enabled scripts and retry the opration or go back in your browser."

But im running this on a putty window.

how do i get pass this?

Answer (score 0):

i had to add an option --noauth_local_webserver to python quickstart.py and it gave me the link to open on a browser to authenticate